# Recyclerview onViewScrolled called multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Currently working on recyclerview that refreshes every time I choose something.

Everytime I would set again the adapter after I selected a choice.

For example, if I choose Fruit, the recyclerview will change to fruits.

I would attach a new adapter to the recyclerview everytime.

The problem with this is whenever I check on onViewScrolled, it is getting called the same amount as I changed the recyclerview data.

My question is, why does this occurs ? Is it because the old adapter didn't detach ?

If yes, how do I detach it properly ?

Comment: can you add some code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the recycler adapter class. For example, you change some data and scroll down. When your scroll is up and that shows your old data.

Add this code in the adapter class.

```
 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```